# Regex with multiple negative lookbehinds

Tags: c#, .net, regex

There are a few questions here similiar to my problem but i could not make it work whatsoever.

What I need is a regex with a capturinggroup that matches every '**WhatEver**DataSet' where i need to capture the 'WhatEver' part.

However, the match must not start with a dot nor with 'ABC'

Testdata:

```
IShouldMatchDataSet             // should match (entity = IShouldMatch)
ABCIShouldNotMatchDataSet       // shoult not
WhatEver.IShouldNotMatchDataSet // should not
.ShouldNotDataSet               // should not
DataSet                         // should not
```

This is my current progress. The dot matching works but the ABC doesnt.

```
(?<!ABC\w*)(?<!\.\w*)(?<entity>\w+)DataSet
```

I am using [RegexStorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester) as a tester, for reference.

Comment: Why `WhatEver.IShouldNotMatchDataSet` doesn't have `WhatEver.IShouldNotMatch` match? The match doesn't start with '.' and also doesn't start with 'ABC'.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov It is not allowed to contain a dot. So basically only word-charachters hence the \w. The exaple data isnt a list of matches but text where the regex only should match the first line.

Comment: Does this regex work for you? `\b(?<!\.)(?!ABC)\w+(?=DataSet)`

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov yes!. Post as an awnser and i gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the ways to do it - look for word break that is not '.' and is not followed by 'ABC', then after the break take text followed by 'DataSet'.

```
\b(?<!\.)(?!ABC)\w+(?=DataSet)
```

[RegexStorm Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb(%3F%3C!%5C.)(%3F!ABC)%5Cw%2B(%3F%3DDataSet)&i=IShouldMatchDataSet%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20should%20match%20(entity%20%3D%20IShouldMatch)%0D%0AABCIShouldNotMatchDataSet%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20shoult%20not%0D%0AWhatEver.IShouldNotMatchDataSet%20%2F%2F%20should%20not%0D%0A.ShouldNotDataSet%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20should%20not%0D%0ADataSet%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20should%20not)